# How to Interact with chest to open it (Minecraft 1.16.5)

Tags: java, minecraft

I'm currently stuck with opening a chest on my server using a client side mod. I want to send the packet for my client to interact with the chest I'm specifying. I have already achieved this goal in 1.8, where I could do:

```java
BlockPos chestPos; // I got this from somewhere else, not important.

p.sendQueue.addToSendQueue(new C08PacketPlayerBlockPlacement(
        chestPos,(double)chestPos.getY()+0.5D < Minecraft.getMinecraft().thePlayer.posY + 1.7D ? 1:0,
        Minecraft.getMinecraft().thePlayer.getCurrentEquippedItem(),0.0F,0.0F,0.0F));

p.swingItem();
```

This made my player mimic an interaction with my chest at the given `BlockPos`.

Now I want to translate this to 1.16.5 code. I've started by investigating given methods, but I could only find

```java
ClientPlayerEntity player = Minecraft.getInstance().player;
player.swingArm(Hand.MAIN_HAND);
```

as equivalent for the last line of the 1.8 code, but this does only trigger the animation of the arm.

The best thing I could find as a replacement for the `sendQueue` was the `player.connection`, which is an instance of `ClientPlayNetHandler`. This class has a ton of `handleXYZPacket(XYZPacket packet)`-methods, but none that seemed useful...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I eventually abandoned the post, and continued my search. I did find a solution though, so here it is. I'd also like to adress that there is like 0 documentation on the web on the packets of 1.16, so I hope this will be useful to someone in the future.

I decided at some point to investigate all the packets that are defined in the `net.minecraft.network.play.client`-package, and found the closest thing to a solution at the time. I contains a class called `CPlayerTryUseItemOnBlockPacket` which seems to be exactly what I need. However, at first all usages I could find, required a `ServerPlayerEntity`, or rather it's connection. Eventually though...

After a very frustrating hour I finally got this to work:

```java
Minecraft.getInstance().player.connection.sendPacket(
new CPlayerTryUseItemOnBlockPacket(Hand.MAIN_HAND, blockRayTraceResult));
```

Here's how I got the blockRayTraceResult of the block the player is currently looking at:

```java
public static BlockRayTraceResult getLookingAt() {
        PlayerEntity player = Minecraft.getInstance().player;
        World world = Minecraft.getInstance().world;
        double rayLength = 100d;
        Vector3d playerRotation = player.getLookVec();
        Vector3d rayPath = playerRotation.scale(rayLength);

        Vector3d from = player.getEyePosition(0);
        Vector3d to = from.add(rayPath);

        RayTraceContext rayCtx = new RayTraceContext(from, to, RayTraceContext.BlockMode.OUTLINE, RayTraceContext.FluidMode.ANY, player);
        return world.rayTraceBlocks(rayCtx);
    }
```